# Como manipular datos generados de un foreach con mismo id en php con js vanilla?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, foreach, id

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    var formEraseP = document.querySelector("#erasePoem");
    formEraseP.onsubmit = function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let requestErP = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
        let ajaxUrl = base_url+'savePoema/erasePoema';
        let formData = new FormData(formEraseP);
        requestErP.open("POST",ajaxUrl,true);
        requestErP.send(formEraseP);
        requestErP.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(requestErP.readyState == 4 && requestErP.status == 200){
                let objData = JSON.parse(requestErP.responseText);
                if(objData.status){
                    let boxAviso = document.querySelector('#boxAviso');
                    let aviso = document.querySelector('#taviso');
                    boxAviso.style.display = "flex";
                    aviso.innerText = objData.msg;
                    formPost.reset();
                    window.location.reload();
                }else{
                    let boxAviso = document.querySelector('#boxAviso');
                    let aviso = document.querySelector('#taviso');
                    boxAviso.style.display = "flex";
                    aviso.innerText = objData.msg;
                }
            }           
        }
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<?php foreach($_SESSION['poemas'] as $val){ ?>
                    <div class="cajapost">
                        <div class="cajat">
                            <h3><?= $val['titulo_poema'];?></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cajacon">   
                            <p><?= $val['poema']; ?></p>
                            <p><?= $_SESSION['userData']['nombre_autor'];?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cajab" id="cajab">
                            <form name="erasePoem" id="erasePoem">
                                <input type="hidden"  name="poemId" value="<?= $val['id_poema'];?>">
                                <button type="submit" class="eraseP">
                                    <span class="icon-trash-can1"></span>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Hola tengo un foreach que trae como posteos con php y genera elementos html la cosa es que el form para eliminar tiene un solo id y se repite por el foreach y al momento de selecionarlo con js vanilla para pasarlo por ajax no lo toma por existir mas elemento con ese id, como se hace en ese caso?

Comment: No tengo muy claro el contexto, pero por qué no manejas el ID de cada post?

Comment: Porque el form lo genera php con el foreach ! para guardar un id de un session

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar el código relevante, cómo generas la tabla y cómo tratas de acceder al ID.

Comment: Ahi lo agregue creo que se agrega asi, perdon es que no se todavia manejar bien esta plataforma, gracias

Comment: Trata de generar tus post con un **for normal** y al id le agregas la posicion de ese **for** de esta forma el id no se repetirá, o hay otra forma de identificar cada post ?? si es asi, pasalo en el boton de eliminar como **data-id** cuando hagas click sobre el boton obtienes esa **data** y solo eliminaras ese post.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi pero ahora tengo problemas para que quede seleccionado y se envie el id del post a enviar! Ya que cuando lo tomo es un nodelist y le llega al php como undefined :c